# Change the way my nodejs app activates

Tags: javascript, node.js, search-engine

The code listed below searches for files that contains a specified string under it's directory/subdirectories.

to activate it, you type node [jsfilename] [folder] [ext] [term]

i would like to change it so it will search without the base folder, i don't want to type `./` , just node [jsfilename] [ext] [term]
so it already know to search from it's location.
i know it has something to do with the `process.argv` but it need a hint what should i do.

PS:.
I already tried to change the last raw to :
searchFilesInDirectory(__dirname, process.argv[3], process.argv[2]);
it giving me noting...

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

function searchFilesInDirectory(dir, filter, ext) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        console.log(`Welcome! to start, type node search [location] [ext] [word]`);
         console.log(`For example: node search ./ .txt myterm`);
        return;
    }


    const files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    const found = getFilesInDirectory(dir, ext);
     let printed = false 

    found.forEach(file => {
        const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(file);

     
        const regex = new RegExp('\\b' + filter + '\\b');
        if (regex.test(fileContent)) {
            console.log(`Your word has found in file: ${file}`);
        }
        if (!printed && !regex.test(fileContent)) {
        console.log(`Sorry, Noting found`);
        printed = true;


     }
     });
     }



     function getFilesInDirectory(dir, ext) {
     if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        console.log(`Specified directory: ${dir} does not exist`);
        return;
    }


     let files = [];
     fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
        const filePath = path.join(dir, file);
        const stat = fs.lstatSync(filePath);

       

        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            const nestedFiles = getFilesInDirectory(filePath, ext);
            files = files.concat(nestedFiles);
        } else {
            if (path.extname(file) === ext) {
                files.push(filePath);
            }
        }
    });


    return files;
}

searchFilesInDirectory(process.argv[2], process.argv[4], process.argv[3]);
```

Comment: If you want the current directory, try -> `process.cwd()`

Comment: i'm really surprised the system let you post this title. please summarize the problem in the title and avoid putting tags in the title.

Comment: My mistake, wont happen again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get what are you trying to achieve. You can do so by slightly changing your function call in the last line.

Change

```
searchFilesInDirectory(process.argv[2], process.argv[4], process.argv[3]);
```

to

```
searchFilesInDirectory(process.cwd(), process.argv[3], process.argv[2]);
```

**Edit**
As @Keith said in comments use `process.cwd()` to get the current working directory instead of `__dirname`

Comment: `__dirname` is a constant inside the module,. not necessary where he is running the command from.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to work for both conditions then you need to do a conditional check...

```
if(process.argv.length === 5){
  searchFilesInDirectory(process.argv[2], process.argv[4], process.argv[3]);
}else if(process.argv.length === 4){
  searchFilesInDirectory(process.cwd(), process.argv[3], process.argv[2]);
}else{
  throw new Error("Not enough arguments provided..");
}
```

Comment: Changed last part to:  console.log("Not enough arguments provided..");

than it works even better.